# RewriteRule delete

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, smarty

I want to delete this htaccess rule:

```
RewriteRule ^resendconfirmation/(.*) resendconfirmation.php?userid=$1
```

`resendconfirmation` only appears once in the whole code:

```
<a href="{$baseurl}/resendconfirmation/{$smarty.session.USERID}">resend confirmation</a>
```

Do you know how should I change the latter HTML code so I can delete the htaccess rule?

Comment: What did you tried? It seems to be a quite simple problem, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would assume by changing the `href` to:

```
<a href="{$baseurl}/resendconfirmation.php?userid={$smarty.session.USERID}">re...
```